# Single operation to get latest on the master branch and merge to my feature branch?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

A lot of the time, I just want to make sure I have merged the latest code before I start coding for the day. The steps typically include:

1. Stash and undo my changes on my current dev/feature branch
2. Check out master branch
3. Get the latest code on master
4. Switch back to my branch
5. Merge from master onto my branch

I do this before I code daily to avoid conflicts for when I will ultimately have to merge to master. Is there a simple one button operation for this so I can save time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out this is called [re-basing.](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase#:~:text=What%20is%20git%20rebase%3F,of%20a%20feature%20branching%20workflow.)

Comment: Set `rebase.autoSquash` option to `true` and you end up with just the command `git fetch & git rebase origin/master` to do all that... (and you can create an alias for that)

Answer (score 0):

From your feature branch :

```
git stash
git fetch
git merge origin/master
git stash pop
```

Or more conveniently with an alias :

```
git config --global alias.up '!git stash && git fetch && git merge origin/master && git stash pop'

# then each time you need it, from your feature branch :

git up
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple. Understand git rebase. [URL](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)